# set UIslider thumb image in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I want to set thumb of like musi app here is ss

I want

[image]

I have

[image]

Here is code

```
        durationSlider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "Slider_indicator.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    durationSlider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "Slider_indicator.png"), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
```

Comment: yes return image and show it

Comment: my problem is thumb image upper part not show like 1st image i want like this

Comment: you don't want to show the above part of the thumb image on slider, Right ?

Comment: Check out my answer, set that image as your thumb image. I have implemented that in one of my project

Comment: could u tell me how to create video app @John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to clip the top part of the thumbImage, you should use:

```
public func thumbRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect, trackRect rect: CGRect, value: Float) -> CGRect
```

So add this to your code:

```
durationSlider.thumbRectForBounds(...)
```

And set the `CGRect` of the `thumbRect` to have the value of `durationSlider.frame.origin.y` as its own `origin.y`.

Here's another temporary solution, I'll get back to the `thumbRectForBounds` method shortly:

```
let mask = CAGradientLayer(layer: durationSlider.layer)
let lineTop = (durationSlider.bounds.height/2 - 0.5) / durationSlider.bounds.height
mask.frame = durationSlider.bounds
mask.colors = [UIColor.clearColor().CGColor, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor]
mask.locations = [lineTop, lineTop]
durationSlider.layer.mask = mask
```

Answer (score -1):

here you want to show only below part of the thumb now. so you need to make above half image clear. Please check the image i have attached with the answer

```
[slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

[image]

Try this and download scale the image if you need