# How to properly set a custom image for a UISlider thumb?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to customize the UISlider thumb image since it seems to be no way to reduce the size of the default image.

I've set the slider image:

```
slider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "thumb_image"), for: .normal)
```

And implemented a custom UISlider to calculate the thumb rect:

```
class MySlider: UISlider
{
    override func thumbRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, trackRect rect: CGRect, value: Float) -> CGRect
    {
        let thumbWidth: CGFloat = 15
        return CGRect(
            x: (bounds.width - thumbWidth) * CGFloat(value),
            y: bounds.midY - thumbWidth / 2,
            width: thumbWidth,
            height: thumbWidth)
    }
}
```

The result I get is the following:

[image: iOS 12] (iOS 12)
[image: iOS 13] (iOS 13)

Regardless of the custom thumb image I set, it always displays the default thumb image resized by my implementation of `thumbRect(forBounds:trackRect:value:)`.

I already managed to retrieve the actual size of the default image and the amount of transparent space around it, so that a can correctly resize and position it. But this only works on iOS 13 and my deployment target is iOS 11.

Comment: Hope it's help's your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35270055/3683408

Comment: Thanks @Ram, I've already seen it but it doesn't help